# Como desinstalo la version de python en macos

Tags: python, python-3.x, ios, macos

Restableci el sistema operativo y al ejecutar en mi terminal sin haber instalado ningun paquete de python  ya que he instalado mis paquetes con homebrew me aparece una version de 3.9.6 al ejecutar python3 -V.

Chequee en las actividades del sistema y se encontraba ejecutando python y detuve el proceso y aun asi todo folder con python3.9 lo elimine enviadolo a la papelera y previamente vaciandola como puedo eliminar por completo esta version.

Comment: MacOS no es Windows, de hecho, en ningún sistema operativo se recomienda borrar carpetas para eliminar programas o características. Creo que en MacOS debes hacerlo desde la terminal usando `homebrew` y, de hecho, si MacOS es como Linux, no es recomendable desinstalar Python, porque es una dependencia del sistema operativo. De cualquier forma, revisa [esta guía](https://python-guide-es.readthedocs.io/es/latest/starting/install3/osx.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenas tardes, un gusto en saludar.

puedes intententar

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3
```

y luego trata de intalar la versión que quieras, si queires siempre primero si quedó algo por ahí

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Sino con el mismo brew puedes instalar alguna versión que prefieras

```
brew install pyenv
```

luego ves la versión

pyenv install

espero que te haya sido de ayuda